# Python get value of variable from RAM

Tags: python

Is it possible, using Python to get a value of a variable from RAM using an address, something like Cheat Engine?

Comment: Python is not C although there is a C implementation of Python.

Comment: Probably not, but you can call C methods that might do such a thing from Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Python module [hackManager](https://github.com/SirFroweey/hackManager), and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's really implementation dependent, you could try this in CPython with `ctypes.string_at` function (it dumps whole Python3 integer structure):

```
import ctypes
from sys import getsizeof

my_value_1 = int(1)
my_value_2 = int(2)

b1 = ctypes.string_at(id(my_value_1), getsizeof(my_value_1))
b2 = ctypes.string_at(id(my_value_2), getsizeof(my_value_2))
print(hex(id(b1)), ''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in b1))
print(hex(id(b2)), ''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in b2))
```

Prints:

```
0x7ffff670ffb0 4d0300000000000040b89d0000000000010000000000000001000000
0x7ffff670f5f0 740000000000000040b89d0000000000010000000000000002000000
```

In other implementations of Python (Jython, Iron Python etc.) this probably won't work. On CPython `id()` returns memory address of the object.